# Dejar de Seguir todas las preguntas eliminadas

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Tengo una duda, y si no, una sugerencia.

¿Existe forma de *Dejar de Seguir* todas las preguntas **[Eliminadas]** de manera inmediata?

Y si no existe, ¿hay la posibilidad de implementar esto?

Como siempre, me dispuse a limpiar esta cola de publicaciones y respuestas seguidas, y como varias veces, me topé con algo como la imagen de abajo.

Hoy mismo tenía 6 páginas, las cuales se redujeron a 2, solo dejando de seguir eliminadas.

Entonces mi **duda/sugerencia** es eso mismo...

¿Hay o podría haber una forma de dejar de seguir todas las preguntas eliminadas de inmediato?

**Imagen del caso:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las preguntas eliminadas, pueden ser recuperadas.. en ese caso, recuperamos tu seguimiento? tambien puede ser que las sigas para que ver que no revivan... (como en mi caso)

Comment: Cuando muchas de ellas ya han pasado de 1 mes, generalmente las dejo de seguir. Si el OP es nuevo y no ha respondido en pocos dias, lo más probable es que no vuelva. Si la pregunta me interesa, la dejo guardada o incluso la marco en otra cola como por ejemplo la de favoritas.